# Exit and re-enter loop in Windows batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need to cycle through a list in a batch file, set a variable, exit the loop and then re-enter.

```
if "%scale%" == "ind" (

    FOR %%A IN %inclpeople% do (
        set person=%%A
        goto :start
        :cyclepeople
        echo  Done %person%
    )
    goto :end
)

set person=%scale%


:start
echo  Starting with %person%
call  %batch%\findperson
      if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :failed


call  %batch%\dosomethingelse
      if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :failed


:finish
if "%scale%" == "ind" (
    goto :cyclepeople
)

:end
call %footer%\success
exit /b 0
```

So, if scale is not "ind" (in this case it could be "all", then go to start and run commands only once.  If scale equals "ind", then loop through a list of people, set person to loop variable, go to start and go back to loop until list is finished, then go to end.

Currently, this works only for the first loop and echos "Done Adam" (e.g. first person), but then goes to end.

Comment: sorry, no `goto`s and labels possible in a `for` or `if` statement. Use `call :label` (looks like you try to emulate just that)

Comment: Thank you!!  This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I will answer the question based on Stephan's comment above:

```
if "%scale%" == "ind" (

    FOR %%A IN %inclpeople% do (
        set person=%%A
        call :start
        echo  Done %person%
    )
    goto :end
)

set person=%scale%


:start
echo  Starting with %person%
call  %batch%\findperson
      if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :failed


call  %batch%\dosomethingelse
      if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :failed


:finish
if "%scale%" == "all" (goto :end)
goto :eof

:end
call %footer%\success
exit /b 0
```